# Cannot find symbol ViewModel with Dagger 2

Tags: android, android-support-library, dagger-2, androidx

I'm creating a new Android project and I adding Dagger 2, but it fails with an error related to `androidx` libraries.

After using a template from within Android Studio, I've added a few lines, `kotlin-kapt`, and the dependencies for Dagger 2.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'

    // Image Loading
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

    // Dagger
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'

    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    // Navigation
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha01'

    // Pretty Logger
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha1'
}
```

When trying to build the application, it fails with the following errors.

```
error: cannot find symbol
public final class MainActivityViewModel extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
                                                                       ^
    symbol:   class ViewModel
    location: package android.arch.lifecycle


error: cannot find symbol
private final androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
                                ^
    symbol:   class MediatorLiveData
    location: package androidx.lifecycle


error: cannot find symbol
private androidx.navigation.NavController navController;
                           ^
    symbol:   class NavController
    location: package androidx.navigation


 ...
```

I've tried with `androidx` libraries, and the older libraries but both fail. If I removed the Dagger 2 dependencies it will build and run fine.

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 17.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show `build.gradle(module:app)`

Comment: @LwinMyoAung I added the remainder of the build.gradle.

Comment: course your error log is mix with `androidx` and `non-androidx` dependencies.I think you should check ur `build.gradle(module:app)`

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that setup at github? I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track down the cause of the issue, it wasn't related to the `build.gradle` itself but the version of Java I was using.

Within Android Studios I have changed the JDK to use Java 10.

However, changing this setting back to using the embedded JDK has made the application compile successful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler**, 
uncheck the '*Configure on demand*' option if set.
Also make sure you are using latest gradle and Android Gradle plugin

Comment: I'm using `tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01`, and `gradle-4.7` for `gradle-wrapper.properties`. I disabled Configure on demand but the issue still remains.

Comment: my current configuration is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3` for android gradle plugin and `gradle-4.4-all.zip` for gradle

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it may be something in combination with Android Studios 3.2.

Comment: so. has anything worked out for you? Please update the answer so others can refer.

Comment: I'm currently working on it, trying to figure out some stuff.

Comment: okay good luck. let us know which method worked for you later